# Switch to accordion on max-width

Tags: html, accordion

I have a small script that changes a div-list into a accordion on a specific (browser) width.

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $( "#footerWidgets" ).accordion();
   } else {
  }
```

It all works fine, but the problem is that when the user views the website on a small screen and increases the browser width (or changes phone to landscape), it won't change back to it's default non accordion position. Wish in result messes up the intire layout. How can I make this possible?

Comment: Can't you just do this with css? what is your CSS code for footerWidgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put it in the resize function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var win_width = $(window).width();
    if ( win_width < 768 ){
        $( "#footerWidgets" ).accordion();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up an `onresize` event handler that rechecks the size of the window when resized and "de-accordianizes" `#footerWidgets`.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $("#footerWidgets").accordion("destroy");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to call this in your resize function

```
$( "#footerWidgets" ).accordion( "destroy" )
```